# Phone detected into Zune but not in my computer

Tags: sync, photos, storage, 7.x, pc

I am using Nokia Lumia 610 . I connected it with PC . The Zune software detects it . Now here's the worst part . My Computer doesn't show my phone or maybe doesn't even detect . Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 devices will only show up in Zune as they can't be shown as a mass media device (like an USB stick).

Comment: iSN'T THERE A WAY TO DO SO?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: It is possible with Windows Phone 8 devices, unfortunately your device is too old to upgrade. Please accept the answer if you have no further questions or comments.